# sudo apt-get update isn't working / networking problem

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, apt, update, rpi-update

I am getting following errors repeatedly upon using apt-get update command :

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
>
> Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
>   Cannot initiate the connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80
>   (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
>   [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]

Also the browser isn't responding .

```
> ping 8.8.8.8 
> 
> --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics --- 31 packets transmitted, 17 received, 45% packet loss, time 30916ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
> 11775.196/12892.493/14139.220/823.235 ms, pipe 14
> 
> ping google.com
> 
> --- google.com ping statistics --- 53 packets transmitted, 44 received, 16% packet loss, time 52627ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
> 25.593/2131.382/8357.227/3445.900 ms, pipe 9
```

I tried to connect with a ethernet cable from my laptop and directly from Wi-fi but I got the same results.

My **ifconfig -a**

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.137.243  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.137.255
        inet6 fe80::75cc:3f56:9969:b109  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:3f:31:ef  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10459  bytes 860119 (839.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10885  bytes 3849492 (3.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 17  bytes 1004 (1004.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17  bytes 1004 (1004.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:6a:64:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 56  bytes 6424 (6.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62  bytes 9557 (9.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My **route -n**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.137.1   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.137.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

MY **/etc/resolv.conf**

```
# Generated by resolvconf
domain mshome.net
nameserver 192.168.137.1
```

Comment: Why are you testing your IPv4 connectivity when your problem is with an IPv6 connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 at IPv6 address `2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3`?